# Need help to make space ind the bondings \chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to build a Sucrose structure scheme in LaTex but i have some trouble. I can't figure out why i can't make the binding between the vertical H's longer so there is more space for the structure

```
\chemfig[][scale=0.8]{C(-[3]HO)(-[5]H)*6(-C(-[6]HO)(-[5]H)-C(-[6]HO)(-[5]H)-C(--0--C(-[3]HO)(-[5]H)*6(-C(-[6]HO)(-[5]H)-C(-[6]HO)(-[5]H)-C(-[7]CH_2OH)(-[6]H)-O-C(-[3]CH_2HO)-))(-[7]HO)(-[6]H)-O-C(-[3]CH_2HO)(-[9]H)-)}\\
```

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/55f6cd36474af9891848c888

Comment: You can use the second argument of the bonds: `-[6,2]H` will make the bond twice as long. (BTW: I'd try to make the bonds to the hydroxy groups end at the O rather than the H. This can easily be done by specifying arrival atoms – another option of the bonds, described in the manual)

Comment: Thanks Clemens. but i am having a problem now! i can't figure out how to add the third group....... can you see where i should add it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a comma first.

Like this

```
(-[,6]H)
```

not

```
(-[6]H)
```

Comment: This is making my vertical bonding between h-h going horizontal instead?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Now I see your problem … and a solution to your problem. The first number is the direction of the bond. After this number there is another option for the length of the bond. (-[6,2]H) means that the bond is twice as long. (-[6,3]H) means that the bond is three times als long and so on. You can also add numbers like this: (-[6,1.5]H) (one and half times als long.)

Comment: Thanks that did it! it is getting way to complicated for me to get a good overview!